# Unique identifier for SlideMaster

Tags: vba, powerpoint

While I realize that a SlideMaster has a unique name in a given presentation (though I understand this to be buggy), is there a way to uniquely identify a master that a user can't touch? Alternatively, is there an equivalent to the Slide's Tags collection, somewhere I can stash my own ID?

For PowerPoint 2003 and/or 2007... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I initially thought there was no good way to protect a SlideMaster name from a user, because it seems to be very easily provided via the Master view. In 2007, this is very easy to get to, as indicated above: View tab of ribbon, Slide Master button, right-click any master, and rename. Pretty much the same in 2003, View menu > Master > Slide Master, right-click the master in question in the lefthand thumbnail list, rename.

The happy fact is that this does not rename the *master* but rather the *design*. The Ppt object model is not very straightforward when it comes to these two objects; each master is apparently the parent of a design, but for all intents and purposes, they are employed 1-to-1, and each exposes the other as a property: `SlideMaster.Design` (for the "active" slide master only) or `Design.SlideMaster` (at least as far as the *slide* master is concerned--I'm not working with the other three, so can't really speak to them here). When the user follows the series of steps detailed above, the equivalent vba is `myDesign.Name = "SomeNewName"`, not `mySlideMaster.Name = "SomeNewName"`. The master's name is unaffected; likewise, if in VBA I execute `mySlideMaster.Name = "SomeNewVBAName"`, the corresponding Design name a user might have chosen remains intact.

Answer (score 0):

In PowerPoint 2007/2010 you can use `CustomXMLParts` as sort of a tag. Here's a demo:

```
Sub SetSlideMasterTag()
    Dim ap As Presentation
    Set ap = ActivePresentation
    ''#------------------------
    Dim slideMasterCustomerData As CustomerData
    Set slideMasterCustomerData = ap.SlideMaster.CustomerData
    ''#------------------------
    Dim slideMasterCustomXMLPart As CustomXMLPart
    Set slideMasterCustomXMLPart = slideMasterCustomerData.Add
    slideMasterCustomXMLPart.LoadXML ("<Tag><Item>SlideMaster</Item></Tag>")
    ''#------------------------
    Dim slideMasterTag As String
    slideMasterTag = slideMasterCustomXMLPart.Id
    ''#------------------------
    Debug.Print slideMasterTag
    Debug.Print ap.CustomXMLParts.SelectByID(slideMasterTag).XML
    ''#------------------------
    ap.CustomDocumentProperties.Add Name:="SlideMasterTag", LinkToContent:=False, _
        Type:=msoPropertyTypeString, Value:=slideMasterTag
End Sub
Sub RetrieveSlideMasterTag()
    Dim ap As Presentation
    Set ap = ActivePresentation
    ''#------------------------
    Dim slideMasterTag As String
    slideMasterTag = ap.CustomDocumentProperties.Item("SlideMasterTag").Value
    Debug.Print slideMasterTag
    ''# Is this the right slide master?
    If Not ap.SlideMaster.CustomerData(slideMasterTag) Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "Found you, you little bugger!"
    End If
End Sub
```

A couple of things to remember:

- You have to maintain the
  `slideMasterTag` between sessions.
  Probably the best place to do this is
  in the `CustomDocumentProperties`,
  hence the `RetrieveSlideMasterTag`
  routine. It is highly unlikely that
  an end user would go into here.

  - If you didn't want to do add this to
    `CustomDocumentProperties`, you would
    just need to query all
    `CustomXMLParts` using XPath for your
    XML.
- The code above doesn't do any error
  or validation checking. You'll need
  to see create code to ensure that
  there is not already a tag called
  `slideMasterTag`.

Comment: Thanks for this. I unfortunately need a solution that also works pre-2007, but the OpenXML direction you describe (also informative post here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_jones/archive/2009/03/05/how-to-assemble-multiple-powerpoint-decks.aspx) bodes well for the future. I think, however, that I can in fact use the SlideMaster.Name property, as I will explain more fully later when I have the time.

Comment: Ah, you had said *PowerPoint 2003 and/or 2007*, so I assumed just 2007 would be fine. `SlideMaster.Name` is definetely changable by an end-user, but if you're willing to take the risk that more than 99% of users don't know how to change that, it should be fine to use it.

Comment: How can a user change SlideMaster.Name?

Comment: @downwitch: Pretty easy if they know what they are doing. here's an example with 2007. Go to the **View** tab, then click on **Slide Master**. Make sure the top-most slide is selected (the big one). Then click on **Rename**. Easy as that in 3 steps.

Comment: Actually, no. It has taken me forever to post this, but I address that below.